# Getting error for Input Validator for org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException

Tags: csv, validation, owasp, esapi

I have expression of
Validator.Format=^(csv|excel|Csv|Escel|CSV|EXCEL)$

Getting error
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidatornException: Invalid input. Please conform to regex
^(csv|excel|Csv|Escel|CSV|EXCEL)$ with maximum length of 5

Can you please suggest

Comment: @398701 can u please address this

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to go on here. You at least need to say what version of ESAPI you are using and show me the full exception message. In the latest version of ESAPI at least, this exception only shows up here, in StringValidationRules.java as:

```
throw new ValidationException( context + ": Invalid input. Please conform to regex " + p.pattern() + ( maxLength == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? "" : " with a maximum length of " + maxLength ), "Invalid input: context=" + context + ", type(" + getTypeName() + ")=" + p.pattern() + ", input=" + input + (NullSafe.equals(orig,input) ? "" : ", orig=" + orig), context );
```

So display the rest of that exception message for starters.